# How to delete related records on other table

Tags: laravel

I tried this

```
 CreatedPlan::where('meal_type_id',config('const.PLAN.__MORNING_MEAL'))->whereYear('calendar_date', $targetYear)->whereMonth('calendar_date',$targetMonth)->get();
```

However following error happened.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`plan`.`created_plans_foods`, CONSTRAINT `created_plans_foods_created_plan_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`created_plan_id`) REFERENCES `created_plans` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `created_plans` where `__id` = 1 and year(`calendar_date`) = 2022 and month(`calendar_date`) = 04) in file /Users/Developments/plan/bb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 669

I tried to  delete the records of the related table.

Comment: You have an SQL constraint that is preventing you from deleting those `CreatedKondate` records if they have rows in the related `created_kondates_foods` table. You'll need to either delete those associated records first, or modify your SQL constraint to "cascade" on delete and let it be done automatically.

Comment: if you can update the table structures take a look at [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) specifically using `cascadeOnDelete`

Comment: I have added cascadeOnDelete on the migration. however nothing changed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are deleting the record of the parent table first and then the child table. This is why laravel gives you the error.
In order to delete this type of case first delete the child table data and then delete the parent table data.
Suppose you have table name users and the other is users_info. The user id is the parent key in the users_info table. so do the following :
First delete from user_info

```
UserInfo::where('user_id',$userId)->delete();
```

Then delete it from the users. Hope this will solve your problem .

```
User::where('id',$userId)->delete();
```